# tensorflow pow function is slow

Tags: performance, tensorflow, logarithm, pow, exp

I am using tensorflow for accelerating a stiff chemistry solver.  In the process, I often have to calculate tf.pow(a,b) where a is a tensor and b is a constant.  During profiling, I found that tf.pow was quite slow, even slower than tf.exp.  I was surprised by that so I calculated the power as tf.exp(tf.log(a)*b) and timed it.  To my surprise, the exponental log was twice as fast as tf.pow.  Why is that? It was quite unexpected.

I should mention I am using single precision floats as my tensors, and I'm running on windows with python 3.6 and tf v1.5 on a CPU using the pip installed whl file using conda

Answer (score 2):

I believe Tensorflow's `exp` and `pow` operations are calling Eigen's implementations. It appears that Eigen is using SIMD instructions for `exp` but not for `pow`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html